# How to enable chrome:webrtc-internals in electron to download webrtc getstats files

Tags: download, electron, webrtc

we  are trying to download the logs from chrome://webrtc-internals, The approach is open chrome://webrtc-internals in electron background when the call is accepted and download stats file when call is ended in electron app. Whats the approach?

Answer (score 1):

The good approach would be sending the stats by calling getStats API on peerconnection. This way you can avoid to opening the chrome://webrtc-internals and sending it after the call terminates.

More information on getStats API can be found here - https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/

You can poll the stats every 10-15 seconds and send it to your back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any examples on how to implement this get stats api

Comment: Chk this - https://www.callstats.io/blog/2015/07/06/basics-webrtc-getstats-api, this blog is little old but it should give you an idea.

Comment: This implementation might help you - https://github.com/fippo/rtcstats

Comment: Hi karthik, can you let me know what are the advantages or drawbacks in opening webrtc internals and downloading logs

Comment: getStats gives you lot more information and flexibility for you as you decide the polling interval (How frequently you would like to call getStats). You can get the stats during the call and don't have to wait until the end of the call.
Webrtc internal does the same thing, it calls getStats and plots it for you.

Comment: Hi Karthik, can you tell me how to get getstats for aws connect ?

Comment: I tried pc1.getstats((res)=>{ var standardreport = {}; var reports = res.result(); reports.forEach((report)=>{ console.log(‘test’,report)})}) and getting legacy getstats api how to get promise based api

Comment: You can get promise based stats this way -
pc.getStats()
        .then((stats) => {
          let statsArray = [];
          stats.forEach(report => {
            statsArray.push(report)
          });
          console.log(statsArray);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Error");
        });

Comment: If you can obtain the peer connection in aws connect, then you can call getstats over it. As far as i know aws connect gives only legacy stats even with promise based API.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Electron to above or equal to electron@9.x.

Answer (score 0):

you can also download it by
 `window.open("chrome://webrtc-internals")`
opening webrtc internals